# How to build create-react-app SPAs so that minor changes can be made without rebuilding the entire application

Tags: reactjs, web, build, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app to create Single Page Websites (SPAs). I often have websites with a lot of images and content that require a minor textual change or a minor update. Is there anyway to make these without rebuilding the entire application? If I rebuild it all the image names and everything changes and the whole enchilada has to be uploaded and built for minor changes in content to the website. How can one approach this?I dont want to go back to building in PHP or another platform where individual pages can be tweaked and uploaded without having to upload everything every time there is a minor change. How are you approaching this in building react based websites?

Comment: You can load the data through an API. In that way if you change the data at the backend the data in the frontend will also change on refresh.

Comment: That will involve building an entire backend system for content across the site making it a bigger project. Currently I am not using a backend system and simple websites dont require a backend. How is this generally approached in react? I dont want to throw a mountain at an issue that requies a hammer tap. To create a full content management system with a database is overkill. How can i make small changes without having to rebuild evertime everything and reupload the entire application instead of the page or part with the change? Is anyone else encountering this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding a CRA should not take very long or cost much, you can use a Continuous Integration solution like Netlify to update your site programmatically based on the changes.

Or you can just build an API and write a modular site using the APIs. That is how most CMS work. You should try headless CMSs if you don't want to write all APIs yourself.

Comment: If I have many sections and pages and lot of images and video across these pages, for a minor change,EVERYTHING is rebuilt. This is very expensive and time consuming. If for example I need to change a menu link which or add a small text or ticker, 100 images videos will be rebuilt and reuploading making it very painful. How can this be addressed without going into the drudgery of a full fledged CMS system. Or will I have to revert to PHP which I really dont want to do.

Comment: If you don't want to write PHP, you can use NodeJS or other server-side frameworks with other languages to create a backend server. The site you want to build indeed needs a backend.  JAM stack and SPA won't always the answer, especially in the case of your requirements.

Comment: Lets say that I use an API or a JAM stack on the back end. The issue is mostly regarding the import of images into the SPA. Currently every image is imported using imports in the REACT SPA. Even if the routes to these images come from a back end API, the images themselves will have to be imported into the SPA. They will have to sit in the SPA and can be loaded up based on the url to the images that comes from the back end API. This comes to the same thing. The images will have to be included in the build process.

Comment: The point is that how can one avoid building all images into a react SPA. If it is an image heavy application do all the images have to be transmitted from the server for each image request? Is there any way that the build process of create-react-app can allow images with the same names as the last build, so that the images, videos do not have to be reuploaded on every build, nor do they have to come from an api or server on every request?

Comment: The solution to my issue would be if there is a way to build the create-react-app so that the image, video, music file names remain the same across builds. Is this at all a possibility. In this scenario, after building, I would upload the light changed code, but would not have to upload the heavy media files, each time there is a minor change in the code.

Comment: @Arjuna , single page applications only update the portion of the Page where the data has been changed .So, unless you mess the architecture up , it is not going to rebuild the whole App from ground  .If you have  a backend to refer to and an API to change your Images. ( but if you change the code, it will always rebuild) .Also,  you can use `Redux-persist`  for storing data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just develop frontend code and don't worry about images, videos, texts and so on you should really try and headless cms that will provide contents via API and a nice editorial console for your users.

There are a lot of them, and for sure you will find one that suits your needs.
I work in ContentChef ( full disclaimer here!!!) which also provides a nice SDK in js or typescript so you can easly get started.
If you want to give it a try: https://www.contentchef.io/developers/headless-cms-for-react